# Manual test cases along with Automated test cases of the same test suite in a single report using Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a group of similar test cases grouped in a test suite, but a few are automated with robotframework while the rest are manually executed. I would like to group it all together in the report.

Is there any way where I can enter the Pass/Fail for manual testcases into the field of robotframework , where it can be included in the final report?

I am looking for a keyword which can ask for "entering input" and wait for a value to be entered.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Dialogs library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Dialogs.html) has a keyword specifically for performing a manual step and then letting the user select pass or fail from a dialog. See [Execute manual step](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Dialogs.html#Execute%20Manual%20Step).